# Correlation Between Surfaces

Tags: time-series, correlation, spatial

Suppose I have a set of data that defines a three dimensional surface for each point in time. So you can imagine a surface that is continuously changing across time. Suppose I have a second surface in the same coordinates/space that is also evolving across time. Is there a way to look at the correlation between these surfaces across time? Does this even make sense? Are there established methods for doing this?

Comment: Would I basically be looking at the correlation between matrices across time?

Comment: It seems to me that the approach should depend on what you are interested in. You could calculate correlation separately for each point, and then compare it across different regions of the surface? Or you could calculate the correlation across the whole image for each time point, and then compare across time points?

Comment: Are the surfaces sampled at the same locations every time?  Are they sampled at regular intervals of time?  What underlying question would some kind of correlation answer?  Indeed, could you elaborate on what you mean by "correlation"?  Most likely your question is answered by some branch of spatio-temporal modeling, but that encompasses a wide array of techniques, which is why clarifying and narrowing your question will help.